# Light Weight Actors

Tags: c#, actor

Edit: This was an absolute ignorance on my part which leads to hierarchical locks and can be implemented much cleaner (in fact the right way, in a mutable world) using a pipe-line of messages or Agents. Please consider studying other actor models in .NET (like the one in F#).

What are drawbacks/benefits of this simple Actor model in C# (Well; it's more of a Message Loop actually, but please enlighten me)?

Using this model one can turn any normal, not async class into an actor without employing threading objects. The idea is objects can be like actors and calling methods is like sending messages; and It's thread safe (yet we can shoot ourselves in foot because of mutability; but other that than, it was very helpful).

Sample: 
Assume that I have an Id server:

```
class IdServer
{
    long _count = 0;
    public string Generate()
    {
        _count++;
        return _count.ToString();
    }
}
```

And I will use it as a thread safe actor (and pass it around). Here is a sample:

```
public static Actor<IdServer> globalIdServer = new IdServer().ToActor();
```

And in Task (Thread) 1:

```
var id1 = (from x in globalIdServer
            let newId = x.Generate()
            select newId).Result();
```

And in Task (Thread) 2:

```
var id2 = (from x in globalIdServer
            let newId = x.Generate()
            select newId).Result();
```

And we even can use multiple Actors in one statements.

Actual implementation of Actor internals is:

```
public class Actor<T>
{
    readonly T _process;
    readonly object _lock = new object();
    readonly int _timeout;

    public Actor(T process) : this(process, 10000) { }
    public Actor(T process, int timeout)
    {
        _process = process;
        _timeout = timeout;
    }

    public U Send<U>(Func<T, U> func)
    {
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_lock, _timeout)) throw new TimeoutException();

        try
        {
            return func(_process);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_lock);
        }
    }
}

public static class ActorFx
{
    public static Actor<T> ToActor<T>(this T obj) { return new Actor<T>(obj); }

    public static Actor<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this Actor<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        return source.Send(selector).ToActor();
    }

    public static Actor<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(this Actor<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Actor<TResult>> selector)
    {
        return source.Send(selector);
    }

    public static Actor<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(this Actor<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Actor<TCollection>> collectionSelector, Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        return resultSelector(source.Send(x => x), source.Send(collectionSelector).Send(x => x)).ToActor();
    }

    public static T Result<T>(this Actor<T> source) { return source.Send(x => x); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the way you're (ab)using LINQ. Instead I would use syntax like:

```
globalIdServer.Run(x => x.Generate())
```

This is shorter than your approach and I think it makes it clearer what's going on.

EDIT: Actually, your `Send()` already behaves like that. I don't see what does the LINQ syntax add.

Another option would be to split the server type into interface and implementation and then use metaprogramming to create an implementation that's an actor. You could use libraries like [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) or [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) to do this (actually [PostSharp already contains actors](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Actor-Based-Programming-with-C-50-and-PostSharp-Threading-Toolkit)).

With DynamicProxy, the user code could look something like:

```
IIdServer globalIdserver = new ProxyGenerator()
    .CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<IIdServer>(new IdServer(), new ActorInterceptor());
var id = globalIdserver.Generate();
```

Another advantage of the metaprogramming approach is that it means the implementation can't escape. With your LINQ approach (or my proposed `Run()`), you can easily do something like:

```
Actor<IdServer> globalIdServer = …;

IdServer escaped = globalIdServer.Result();

escaped.Generate(); // not under lock!
```

---

If you can use C# 5.0, consider making waiting for the lock asynchronous, so that you're not blocking a thread unnecessarily.

---

```
var id1 = (from x in globalIdServer
            let newId = x.Generate()
            select newId).Result();
```

There is no reason to use `let` here, `select` is enough:

```
var id1 = (from x in globalIdServer
           select x.Generate()).Result();
```

And method syntax is probably even better:

```
var id1 = globalIdServer.Select(x => x.Generate()).Result();
```

---

```
public Actor(T process) : this(process, 10000) { }
```

Why is the default timeout 10 s? Wouldn't `Timeout.Infinite` be a better default?

---

```
public static class ActorFx
```

The usual convention is to call the static class that contains extension methods something like `ActorExtensions`.